# Powershell: Function Prompt In Ps1 Script

Tags: powershell

Want to pull off something similar to " `set /p variable = x` " from batch.

How can we make this happen in PS1?

Script example that im using

```
Function Prompt { 'PS' + $x + '>' }
```

Comment: Inside the function, first determine the value for `$x` I would imagine..

Comment: What does the `set /p variable = x` actually do for your in batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to `set /p` in PowerShell would be [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host):

```
$value = Read-Host "Give me some input"
```

The host application (eg. `powershell.exe`) will now prompt the user for input with the caption `Give me some input:`, and the result will be stored in `$value`

[image]

Comment: This indeed is exactly what I asked for, thank you.